# leipzig.sty: How to change the name of glossary

Tags: glossaries, linguistics, leipzig

I wish to change the name of the abbreviations list, which defaults to `Abbreviations`. The package documentaion tolds that redefining `\leipzigname` would work, but it did not work.

Here is the code:

```
¥documentclass{article}

¥usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
¥makeglossaries
¥renewcommand{¥leipzigname}{list}

¥begin{document}
¥printglossary 
¥Nom{}
¥end{document}
```

And it goes like this:
[image: Abbreviations]

How can I change it?

Comment: This works fine for me (when I change your ¥ to \ ).

Answer (score 0):

Put `\renewcommand{\leipzigname}{New name here}` before `\makeglossaries`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mcolblock]{leipzig}
\renewcommand{\leipzigname}{New name here}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\leipzigname}{list}

\begin{document}
\printglossary 
\Nom{}
\end{document}
```